# how to check if i have successfully disabled dm-verity?

Tags: rooting, dm-verity

my phone has dm verity enabled by default. I read about ways to disable it. After that, is there any way with which can i verify if dm-verity is disabled?

Answer (score 1):

All that dm-verity usually mean is that you have write access to the /system partition. So trying to write to (or place) any file in there should be enough.

Be careful though, modifying /system is always risky.